# php, to return all the elements in an integer array which bigger than a integer stored in a variable

Tags: php, arrays

ell, my first thought was to use array_filter function looks something like this:

```
function gettime(){


$cityciqurechangetime = an array of integers;
$iniFirstLegEndTime = an integer calculated by other methods;

$CitySquareTimearray = array_filter($cityciqurechangetime, 
                                   function($n){global $iniFirstLegEndTime ;
                                   return $n >= ($iniFirstLegEndTime);});

return $CitySquareTimearray;

}
```

But it's not working, i ran a few tests and the results indicated that the variable $iniFirstLegEndTime has never passed to the callback function in the array_filter() function so the $CitySquareTimearray variable is just the entire array $cityciqurechangetime.

I once thought maybe i shouldn't declare a function in the array_filter() function but the following one works perfectly where $starttimetabletime is
an array of time stamps.

```
$initStartTimearray = array_filter($starttimetabletime, 
                                    function($n) 
                                    {return $n >= time();});
```

What i really want is an "sub-array" of $cityciqurechangetime with all element is greater or equal than $iniFirstLegEndTime, please tell me what i did wrong or if there are better ways to solve this problem other than using array_filter() function please teach me, thank you very much.

Comment: You use global inside of anon function, but do not globalize in gettime(). It will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement is incorrect. Here is an updated version of your script:

```
function gettime(){


    $cityciqurechangetime = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $iniFirstLegEndTime = 2;

    $CitySquareTimearray = array_filter($cityciqurechangetime, function($n) use ($iniFirstLegEndTime){
        return $n >= ($iniFirstLegEndTime)?$n:null;
    });

    return $CitySquareTimearray;

}

var_dump(gettime());
```

You should be using array filter, as it is much more performant then iterations over arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The updated function provided by @null05 above is the correct way to avoid the use of the `global` keyword and the return statement can be further simplified without the use of ternary operators.

```php
function gettime() {
    $cityciqurechangetime = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $iniFirstLegEndTime = 2;

    $CitySquareTimearray = array_filter($cityciqurechangetime, function($n) use ($iniFirstLegEndTime) {
        return $n >= $iniFirstLegEndTime;
    });

    return $CitySquareTimearray;
}

var_dump(gettime());
```

The callback within `array_filter` returns a boolean to inform `array_filter` which items to include in the `$CitySquareTimearray` array.